# How to force a tool resolve with a tortoisehg merge

Tags: tortoisehg

To my knowledge, the tortoisehg merge scheme works like this

> Mercurial's merge algorithm looks like this (simplified):
>
> - determine the files modified by each branch, using a common ancestor as a shared starting revision
> - for each file that was modified on one branch, take that changed version
> - for each file that was modified on both branches, perform a file merge

Avoiding step 3 is a pretty simple matter.  You can easily force a tool resolve for conflicts.

My question is, how do you avoid step 2?  I would like to force a tool resolve for all files with a change.

The truly annoying part is that with large and complicated merges, tracking down all the files that where auto updated is not fun.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're wanting to do this. I don't have problems tracking down files, and I'm not sure how avoid step 2 would help that. Can you explain the ultimate goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @mo I want a merge to be completely manual.  I want to decide whether to take a change or not. I don't want to have to go back after the fact find updates mercurial did on it's own and verify them.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't come across as making light of your question but I'm still having difficulty seeing a practical application of it.

Anyway! I'm not sure of the best way to do this with TortoiseHg or command line mercurial (or if it's even possible), but with a diff tool and a bit of wrangling, I managed something that might meet your needs. If this is useful, it would be easy to automate some of the wrangling :)

I typically use BeyondCompare, but it doesn't support 3-way folder compare (although see [this post](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=5064)). So for this I used KDiff (that comes with TortoiseHg).

1. First, right click on each head and export > archive > Directory of files (pick whatever target folders you like).
2. Next, do the same on the common ancestor (easily done by selecting both changesets, right clicking and choosing "Goto common ancestor").
3. Now open KDiff3 and choose the three folders created above. KDiff's output should very intuitively show all files that are different in either branch.
4. Checking the "Merge" box (and providing a fourth destination directory) while performing the previous step will allow you to manually merge everything as you please.
5. Getting the result of the merge back into a new mercurial changeset, although cumbersome, should be conceptually straightforward.

[image: Sample output from KDiff3]

I hope this suits your purposes. Let me know if you have need of clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess at this since I don't use hg.

Perhaps you can force it to be interactive by using:
hg --config ui.interactive=yes

Secondly if that doesn't work, you might be able to specify a custom merge tool which has a different behavior for one sided changes. Or specify the rule: internal:prompt so that it always asks what to do, and presumably gives you the chance to do a diff before accepting the changes.

Ref: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#id4

Comment: I don't know about the config option, but I know step two is performed by mercurial independent of the merge tool.